# Is is possible to get facet results for a CMIS query?

Tags: solr, alfresco, cmis, facet

I plan to use CMIS for executing full text queries against the documents stored in an Alfresco repository. For this i want to use the CONTAINS() filter. This gives me a result set ... but my question is: how do i retrieve the facet counts?

Alfresco uses Solr in the background to execute the queries. Is there a way to specificy the facet fields and to get their results via CMIS?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Facets are a Solr feature that is not mapped in CMIS domain model. If you need facets, you will have to directly use Solr instead of CMIS.